# How to call javascript function multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, openweathermap

I am using an API from OpenWeatherMap on my website to show weather condition of just some specific places only, altogether in one page.
Here's the code:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>


<body>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="dehradun" id="cityName">
  <button onclick="getWeather()">Get weather of Dehradun</button>

  <div class="weatherResponse"></div>
  <br><br>

  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="pune" id="cityName">
  <button onclick="getWeather()">Get weather of Pune</button> '
  <div class="weatherResponse"></div>
  <br><br>

  <script>
    function getWeather() {
      $('.weatherResponse').html('');
      var cityName = $('#cityName').val();
      var apiCall = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName + '&mode=json&units=metric&appid=<apikey>';
      $.getJSON(apiCall, weatherCallback);

      function weatherCallback(weatherData) {
        var cityName = weatherData.name;;
        var country = weatherData.sys.country;
        var description = weatherData.weather[0].description;
        var temp = weatherData.main.temp;

        $('.weatherResponse').append("The Weather in " + cityName + " " + country + " is currently " + description + " with temperature: " + temp);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Suppose if i want to show weather condition of two places using the same Javascript function then its showing the same result for both the places(Of place (Dehradun) mentioned first in code).

Help me solve this problem.

Comment: You should be using class instead of ID, and your problem will be solved

Comment: You mean inside the <input> tag? ...If so then i tried, its not working.

Comment: I have added a working code by passing value to the function and updating your IDs , will clean up the code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can Pass both your city name and div (display results) as function parameter**

```js
 function getWeather(cityName, className)
 {
 
  $('.'+className+'').html('');

  var apiCall= 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName + '&mode=json&units=metric&appid=d3d913fca612366a61837ea39a622480';
  $.getJSON(apiCall,weatherCallback);

  function weatherCallback(weatherData)
  {
    var cityName= weatherData.name;;
    var country= weatherData.sys.country;
    var description= weatherData.weather[0].description;
    var temp= weatherData.main.temp;

     $('.'+className+'').append("The Weather in " + cityName + " " + country + " is currently " + description + " with temperature: " + temp);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<body>
<button onclick="getWeather('dehradun','wr1')">Get weather of Dehradun</button>
<br><br>
<div class="wr1"></div>
<br><br>
<button onclick="getWeather('pune','wr2')">Get weather of Pune</button>
<br><br>
<div class="wr2"></div>
<br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have roughly added the working code below, when you click on a button it will show the whether report of that city in both the text, Try clicking on both the button and take a look:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>


<body>
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="dehradun" id="cityName2">
<button onclick="getWeather('dehradun')">Get weather of Dehradun</button>

<div class="weatherResponse"></div>
    <br><br>

<input type="hidden" name="name" value="pune" id="cityName1">
<button onclick="getWeather('pune')">Get weather of Pune</button>
    

 <br><br>
<div class="weatherResponse"></div>
<script>
 function getWeather(cityName){
$('.weatherResponse').html('');

var apiCall= 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName + '&mode=json&units=metric&appid=d3d913fca612366a61837ea39a622480';
$.getJSON(apiCall,weatherCallback);

function weatherCallback(weatherData){
var cityName= weatherData.name;;
var country= weatherData.sys.country;
var description= weatherData.weather[0].description;
var temp= weatherData.main.temp;

$('.weatherResponse').append("The Weather in " + cityName + " " + country + " is currently " + description + " with temperature: " + temp);
}
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes now its showing the result of both the cities, thanks a lot. But yes, it shows the result of one in both the text, please help me fix this issue. I think its something to do with the <div class="weatherResponse"> which needs to be change for both.